# QTP Code for permanently enabling MACROS

Tags: excel, qtp, vba

I have a QTP script which opens an excel sheet and update some of my results in the excel work book, but the excel has macros, so everytime when i runs, the alert box asking whether to enable macros pops up.
So i need a QTP script which will premanently enable macros.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use QTP script to enable macros permanently. Another work around for this is to go for trust center settings in Excel. Here you have option to enable or macros or you can disable macros without notification. Once this is done excel won't show any notification to enable macros. You may need to check the "Trust access to VBA project object model"

Assuming that you are using Excel 2007: To access the trust center settings click the office button >> Excel Options >> Trust Center >> Trust Center Settings >> Macro Settings

Note: Its not recommended to enable macros permanently as it may compromise your security.

In addition you can open excel files in background using QTP. Try doing that and check whether the enable macro pop up create problems.